# Excel VBA Chart Generation using Predetermined Templates

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA coding, and I have to automate the creation of different charts of 10+ tables of data. The chart design has to be completely the same as it was when it was done manually.

While I did try to use record macros to create the exact type of chart I need for each table, it doesn't generate the same results. Tweaking the code also takes ages for each chart individually.

While saving the wanted chart types as templates does do the trick for only one user, is it possible to somehow save them as templates in the workbook that is being used, so that the code doesn't break when it is sent to other colleagues to update the charts by adding new data?